# Dynamic Filter Exchange 2010 Powershell

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, exchange-server-2010

I have tried with many different combinations (including brackets). We are using Exchange 2010 Hybrid environment with O365.

Mailboxes that are migrated to the O365, become "Mail Contact" objects and are no longer being included in our Dynamic Distribution Groups.

Basically I want all on-premise user mailboxes, and "Remote User Mailbox" (not all Mail Contacts) to be included in the filter selection. Where organization is "AB*", my attempt is below:

```
Set-DynamicDistributionGroup -Identity "Test Filter Group" -RecipientFilter {RecipientType -eq 'UserMailbox' -or RecipientType -eq  'MailUser' -or RecipientType -eq 'MailContact' -and Company -eq 'AB*' -and isMailboxEnabled -eq '$true' -and ObjectCategory -eq 'person' -or ObjectCategory -eq 'users' -and ObjectClass -eq 'user' -and RecipientTypeDetails -ne '16'}
```

Can someone please help!?

Comment: Have you tried grouping your `-or`/`-and` statements with `()`, making it clear which clauses precede eachother?

Comment: I have indeed. I usually get a; "you must have a command to the right of the -and" error.

Comment: That may indicate that you're doing it wrong :)